# how to pass information to url via excel vba

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I want to use excel vba to control Internet explorer object.

Manually we can setup in "https://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-historical-data"

- Time Frame i.e. "Daily"
- Start Date i.e. "01/01/2016"
- End Date i.e "31/12/2016"

How to do this with excel vba ?

I've this code to open the URL

```
InfiniteLoop = True
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate myURLLink ' should work for any URL

    SleepTime = 10000
    Do
        DoEvents
        Sleep (SleepTime)
        If ie.ReadyState >= 4 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until InfiniteLoop = False
End With
```

But I don't know how to pass

- Time Frame i.e. "Daily"
- Start Date i.e. "01/01/2016"
- Start Date i.e. "01/01/2016"

Can anyone help ?

Comment: The custom dates dialog on the Dow Jones page you've listed doesn't embed the dates you choose into the page url.   If that's the case you won't be able to do it using the method you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with this simple macro (Excel 2010) to navigate to the sit and change the dates and data interval, hopefully it will help:

```
Sub test()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim IEdoc As Object
Dim IEElement As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer 'initialize Internet Explorer

IE.Navigate "https://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-historical-data" 'Navigate to URL
IE.Visible = True

Set IEdoc = IE.Document

Set IEElement = IEdoc.GEtelementbyID("picker") ' navigate to date input
IEElement.Value = "01/01/2016 - 01/01/2017"

Set IEElement = IEdoc.GEtelementbyID("widget") ' navigate to date widget
IEElement.Click
Set IEElement = IEdoc.GEtelementbyID("applyBtn") ' navigate to Apply button to save the dates
IEElement.Click


Set IEElement = IEdoc.GEtelementbyID("data_interval") ' navigate to Interval picker
IEElement.Value = "Daily"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. But I get "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)" on Set IEdoc = IE.Document.  How can I work around this ?